# getText from an EditText that is updated

Tags: android

I have a layout where I have an EditText with a predefined text.

Then I have a button that, when is pressed, displays a dialog with another EditText that gets the text of the previous EditText.

This works fine. But when I edit the first EditText, and press the button again, it displays the old text, not the new.

How can I get the updated text?

This is the code (inside onCreateDialog) where I get the text from the first EditText:

```
final View notesDialogLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.notes_dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(notesDialogLayout)
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       })

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

mNotesEdit = (EditText) notesDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.task_notes_dialog);
mNotesEdit.setText(mNotes.getText());
```

mNotes is just an EditText.

The first time the Dialog opens, it gets the updated text. From the second time, it gets always the same text, even if I edit it.

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: Then you're not updating it right I would say. Since you don't provide any code it's impossible for us to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using onCreateDialog. This method is called once only, you must use onPrepareDialog to set your text in the dialog, which is called each time you call showDialog().

### edit

```
protected void onCreateDialog(int dialogId) {
    View notesDialogLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.notes_dialog, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(notesDialogLayout)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, null)
            .create();
}

protected void onPrepareDialog(Dialog dialog) {
    EditText content = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.task_notes_dialog);
    content.setText(mNotes.getText());
}
```

Comment: Ok, so how can I update the EditText widget text who resides inside my AlertDialog?

Comment: like I said, create your alertdialog in onCreateDialog, like you are doing, but set the text value only in onPrepareDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works

```
      package com.hollow;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

public class HellowActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText editText;
EditText editText2;
Button b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText2.setText(editText.getText());

        }
    });
}
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it displays old value because you enter predefine text in your xml file code.
for solve this..
you have to handle your edittext text string into your java file.
update the that string variable.

```
eg: String myTextInput = "Predefined text";
    EditText edt = (EditText) findViewId(R.id.edt);
    edt.setText(myTextInput);
```

now when u change the text then update the value on your variable like :

```
myTextInput = edt.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement onPrepareDialog but I did not have luck, because I didn't find how to update something that is inside the dialog (like the EditText in my case).

So I ended putting this in my dialog's button:

```
removeDialog(NOTES_DIALOG_ID);
```

And now it is always getting the updated text, as the dialog is removed every time it gets closed.

Comment: this is not the correct approach. I'll edit my post to make it clear